# Computing the iterated logarithm (log-star) by hand

Tags: logarithms, computer-science, recursive-algorithms

I'm having trouble figuring out how to compute the [iterated logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm) (log-star) by hand without using a calculator or programming language. I wrote out the following program in Java to check my answers as I practice but can't seem to wrap my head around how to do this without a computer.

```
public class Recurrences {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Compute log-star (base 2) of 100,000
        System.out.println((int) logStar(100000, 2));

    }

    /**
     * log-star recursive method
     * @param n Value of input
     * @param base Base value for the logarithm (i.e. log base 2 would give 2)
     * @return If n > 1.0, return 1 + logStar( log2(n) ), else return 0.
     */
    public static double logStar(double n, int base) {

        if (n > 1.0) { // Recursive case

            return 1.0 + logStar((Math.log(n)) / (Math.log(base)), base);

        } else { // Base case. If n <= 1, return 0.

            return 0;

        }

    }

}
```

Do you have any tips as to how you would calculate log-star of say, 100000? My program says the answer should be 5 but I don't know how I would go about getting that answer with pen and paper. Also, as shown above in the code, I'm working in log base 2.

Edit: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm) is a link that explains the concept. Sorry for the initial lack of info.

Comment: Can you please give the definition of the log-star operator (by editing your question to include it)?  I don't necessarily trust your code, or (more importantly) my ability to properly parse it.  Also, I'm not really sure how this is a question about computer science (except, perhaps, tangentially, as you have included code in your question)---you may want to consider removing the tag.

Comment: You should define what you mean by log-star, not provide uncommented code and expect people to figure it out.

Comment: I added more clarification, sorry.

Comment: @JacksonBlankenship The table on that Wikipedia page gives you all the answers you need. Or at least all the answers you'll be able to verify with your Java program.

Comment: You still did not define the function except to give a link.  Please make the question self contained.

Comment: To work with numbers that will produce a result much larger than 5, you'd need to use techniques like the ones used in [HyperCalc](http://mrob.com/pub/perl/hypercalc.html). It does calculations in [level-index notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_level-index_arithmetic) which is directly connected to $\log^*$.

Comment: @xander-henderson The tag "computer-science" is perfectly relevant, as the main use of the iterated logarithm is the analysis of algorithms.

Comment: @ross-millikan It is common practice on this site to give a definition through a link on Wikipedia. In the present situation, it is even preferable, since the Wikipedia entry gives some extra information on top of the formal definition.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin If we judge the applicability of a tag on the basis of where the topic of the question is applied, should all question about logistic growth models be tagged (biology) (as per the tag description "For questions regarding mathematical concepts with applications to Biology.")?  The fact that the log-star operator has applications in computer science does not imply that this question is about computer science, as per the tag description.  The (recursive-algorithms) tag seems appropriate here.  I'm not convinced that the (computer-science) tag is...

Answer (score 1):

By hand

- $2^{16} =65536 \lt 100000 \le 131072=2^{17}$
- $2^4 \le 16 \lt \log_2(100000) \le 17 \le 2^5$
- $2^2 \le 4 \lt \log_2(\log_2(100000)) \le 5 \le 2^3$
- $2^1 \le 2 \lt \log_2(\log_2(\log_2(100000))) \le 3 \le 2^2$
- $2^0 \le 1 \lt \log_2(\log_2(\log_2(\log_2(100000)))) \le 2 \le 2^1$
- $0 \lt \log_2(\log_2(\log_2(\log_2(\log_2(100000))))) \le 1$

Five $\log_2$s in the final expression

Comment: It's easier to go the other way and calculate the tower of $2$s and then see what "bucket" the number falls into by simply comparison. Of course, we quickly go beyond numbers which are physically able to be written out in standard notation. Non-standard representations become necessary if one wants to continue.

Comment: @DerekElkins You may be right about efficiency.  My suggestion works by hand and clearly fits the definition. I chose it because is related to the the continuous bijective function $f:\mathbb R_{\ge0} \to  \mathbb R_{\ge0}$ with $f(x)=x$ when $0 \le x \le 1$ and $f(x)=1+f(\log x)$ when $x \ge 1$; when the base of the logarithm is $e$, you find $f(x)$ also differentiable