# How many successive logs until a number becomes $1$?

Tags: logarithms, function-and-relation-composition

I'm wondering if there's a known equation or something that shows how many successive logs of a number it takes for a number to become $1$ as a function of the original number? i.e. $\log(\log...(\log(n)))$

Comment: Typically, this will never happen.  If you iteratively take logarithms of an arbitrary positive real number, you will almost surely obtain a result between 0 and 1 at some step, at which point you are either done, or you start working with complex logarithms.

Comment: Try working backwards to gain some insight. For what value of $n$ does $\log(n)=1$? Then for what value of $m$ does $\log(m)=n$? And so forth

Comment: Why are you assuming that such a formula can even exist?

Comment: Are you looking for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm

Comment: This is the [super-logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-logarithm) with respect to base $e$. The precise definition vary from author to author and no concrete representation of it is available. Look at the wiki entry and refs there for some approach of this problem.

Comment: Dupe. It's log* (log star). https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2553258/510296 - Source Code: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterated-logarithm-logn/ .